# agGrid never ready when reloading angular tab

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-router, ag-grid

I am using `ag-grid: "5.0.3"` in a project with typescript and `angular: "1.5.7"` and `angular-ui-router: "0.3.1"`.

I have a view with multiple tabs in something like this:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-3">
      <uib-tabset justified="true" active="ctrl.activeTabIndex">
         <uib-tab index="$index" ng-repeat="tab in ctrl.tabs" ng-hide="tab.hide" heading="{{tab.heading}}" classes="my-tab"
                         disable="tab.disabled" select="ctrl.go(tab)">
                </uib-tab>
            </uib-tabset>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="panel-body row">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-12">
           <div class="tabsView" ui-view="tabsView"></div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Some of these tabsView contain a `<div ag-grid="ctrl.gridThreeOptions" class="ag-blue"></div>` whose options are created when the main view is loaded.

The problem I am finding is that if I refresh the page or I try to load directly one of the tabs that contains a grid, the grid will be forever stuck in `Loading...` until I click on another tab and go back to the same tab. See image below:

[image]

It's as if the grid was not ready by the time the time the tab view is rendered.
I also noticed that if I refresh the browser on that tab (on that state), the grid options' `onGridReady`event is never triggered. So the grid is never ready.

I have something like this in my main view's controller that loads all the grids' options.

```
private init(): void {
   this.remoteService.getRemoteJsonIncludingAllTablesToDisplay()
         .then((jsonObject: any) => {
              // here I create all the gridOptions for the different tabs with the jsonObject's arrays received
              this.gridOneOptions = gridService.getGridOneOptions();
              this.gridTwoOptions = gridService.getGridTwoOptions();
              this.gridThreeOptions = gridService.getGridThreeOptions();
              this.tabs = this.getTabs(); //gets the array of ITab
              //now I load whatever tab the browser wanted to view:
              this.activeTabIndex = this.getActiveTabIndex();
          });
}

private getActiveTabIndex(): number {
    for (let index = 0; index < this.tabs.length; index++) {
         let tab: any = this.tabs[index];
         if (this.active(tab)) {
             return index;
         }
    }
    return 0; // by default go to first tab
}
```

I have a workaround but it seems ugly. For now what I do is to set a timeout before navigating to the desired tab and then I apply the $scope (it seems necessary for the new tab view to load). Something like this:

```
this.tabs = this.getTabs(); //gets the array of ITab
//now I load whatever tab the browser wanted to view:
let tabToGo: number = this.getActiveTabIndex();
setTimeout(() => {
     this.activeTabIndex = tabToGo
     this.$scope.$apply();
}, 200);
```

Anybody knows why the grid stuck on `Loading...` might happen?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, using the ag-grid in a bootstrap modal dialog. In the end, using a ng-if solved my problems. So you could try this:

```
<div ag-grid="ctrl.gridThreeOptions" ng-if="ctrl.gridThreeOptions != null" class="ag-blue"></div>
```

Comment: that didn't resolve my issue.. The grid keeps in loading state until i refresh the view.